# mysql throws empty error message php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, phpmyadmin

```
   <?php

   if (isset($_COOKIE["username"])) {

$listType = $_POST['listType'];
$uid = $_COOKIE['username'];
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','xxxx','xxxx');
if(!$con)
{
        die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());
}

$db = mysql_select_db('xxx');

$getUseridquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE membername='".$uid."'") or die("error1" .mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getUseridquery)or die("error11" .mysql_error())) {
    $user_id = $row['uid'];
    typeHandler($listType, $user_id);
}

   } else {
       //something wrong
       return failure;
   }

   function typeHandler($type, $id) {
       if ($type == 'sub') {
        //get the list of subscibers if there's any
        $getSubscribe_query = mysql_query("SELECT target_id FROM subscribes WHERE owner_id='" . $id . "'") or die("error2".mysql_error());
           $subArray = mysql_fetch_array($getSubscribe_query);
           $rowcount = mysql_num_rows($getSubscribe_query) or die("error22".mysql_error());
           if ($rowcount > 0) {
            makeSubList($subArray, $id, TRUE);
           } else {
            makeSubList($subArray, $id, FALSE);
           }

       }

       if ($type == '') {

       }

   }

   function makeSubList($iArray, $id, $hasSub) {

if ($hasSub = TRUE) {
    //if user subscribed to others
    $responseArray = array();
    for ($a = 0; $a <= count($iArray); $a++) {
        makeListEntry($iArray[$a], $responseArray);
    }

    //add owner's scene
    makeListEntry($id, $responseArray);
    return $responseArray;
} else {
    //just add ower to the list
    $responseArray = array();
    makeListEntry($id, $responseArray);
    return $responseArray;
}

   }

   function makeListEntry($user_id, $responseArray) {

//scene count
$getSceneInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scene WHERE uid='" . $user_id."'") or die("error3".mysql_error());
$sceneCount = mysql_num_rows($getSubscribe_query)or die("error34".mysql_error());

//latest scene
$getLatestScene = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scene WHERE uid='" . $user_id . "' ORDER BY time_created DESC LIMIT 1") or die("error4".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getLatestScene) or die("error44".mysql_error())){
    $title = $row['title'];
    $time = $row['time_created'];
}


//count follower
$getFollower = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subscribes WHERE target_id='" . $user_id . "'") or die("error5".mysql_error());
$followerCount = mysql_num_rows($getFollower) or die("error54".mysql_error());

//get subscriber info
$getSubInfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid='" . $user_id . "'") or die("error6".mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getSubInfo)or die("error66".mysql_error())){
    $dp = $row['dp_file'];
    $name = $row['name'];
}

//store data response to array
$response = array('name' => $name, 'dp' => $dp, 'title' => $title, 'uploadtime' => $time, 'scenecount' => $sceneCount, 'followercount' => $followerCount);
//store response to page
$responseArray . array_push($response);
   }

   ?>
```

Basically I was trying to retrieval some information from different tables in mySQL and store these data in an array so I can pass them to other JavaScript files using AJAX.

These codes somehow throw MySQL error boxes with no error messages in them.

I have tried assigning additional strings to identify each error message, but it only shows the string I wrote and does not address any error.

P.S. I am using PhpMyAdmin.

Please help.

Comment: Please avoid using deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: First, you need to provide what exactly get's shown. You have lots of calls to mysql, where in the script does the error occur? How are these error messages being popped up?  Secondly you shouldn't be using `mysql_*` functions anyway as they are deprecated and a security hazard. Look into using PDO (http://php.net/PDO) and read about SQL Injection vulnerabilities to understand why.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely look into PDO.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to say if this is the *only* problem, but you cannot check for errors while fetching. `mysql_fetch_*()` return `FALSE` when no rows are left, but that is *not* an error condition:

```
// Don't do this!
// If no rows are found, or as soon as you have fetched all rows,
// it will exit with a bogus error.
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getLatestScene) or die("error44".mysql_error())){}

// Instead check for errors first, then just loop:
$getLatestScene = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scene WHERE uid='" . $user_id . "' ORDER BY time_created DESC LIMIT 1") or die("error4".mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getLatestScene)){}
```

Note: Your script is vulnerable to SQL injection. Filter your input values:

```
$listType = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['listType']);
$uid = mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['username']);
```

But.. it is a vary bad idea to store the username in `$_COOKIE`. Instead, you should be storing that value in `$_SESSION`. Any user could pose as any other user simply by forging a cookie.  We can't see where you are calling `setcookie()`, but you ought not do that. Instead do:

```
// at start of script
session_start();
// Later, store the user in $_SESSION
$_SESSION['username'] = 'the username';
```

Comment: Thank you so much for point out the noob mistake I made. It seems like   the only problem was that I tried to check for errors while fetching.

Comment: The random message box will called somewhere else, which was supposed to output the number of instance in the array. It seems like my array was not written correctly so the message box has no label on it :S

Comment: @JasonLiao It is hard to tell if you are trying to add `$response` onto `$responseArray` or what you're after. If you are trying to join those two arrays, use `$responseArray + $response`. If you are trying to push `$response` onto `$responseArray` as a subarray, use `array_push($responseArray, $response)`

Answer (score 0):

For your AJAX Debugging purposes, your AJAX-Module could

```
die(JSON_encode("mysql_error",mysql_error()))
```

to make your debugging times easier.